# C# How to check if a PictureBox contains an image in a specified imagelist?

Tags: c#

I need to know whether the `PictureBox` contains an `Image` in a specified `imageList`. Because if ImageList is long, it will take a lot to say
in an `if-statement` if each image in `imageList`is in the PictureBox.
and when I type

```
foreach (var image in imageList1)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image = image)
            {
                //Code
            }
        }
```

It doesn't work :/

Comment: How could you do that? The only way, without enumerating the list is to keep track beforehand. Or, if you could create a fingerprint of the image you could use that, but that is not trivial, imo. Obviously it still means to have fingerprints of all images in the list in another list, which would be faster to compare than bitmaps..

Comment: On re-reading the question, I notice that you didn't write 'loop' but 'if-statement'. Obviously that's what loops are for..! But note that comparing images not be trivial either in a loop or in an if-statement as they are reference variables! So it will depend how the pb.image was assigned. Best set the source as a Tag when setting it and you're done!

Comment: Can you write your answer and the code,please?

Comment: ImageList should only ever be used to act as the image source for a ListView or TreeView.  Use a `List<Image>` instead.  Now that foreach loop takes a fraction of a microsecond.

Comment: Please...type the code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
//using System.Linq;

bool isinside = /*yourImageList*/.Images.Any(x => x == /*yourPictureBox*/.Image);

if (isinside)
{
    //is in yourImageList
    MessageBox.Show("image is from imagelist!");
    //or do what you want here!
}
```

Comment: Imagelist.Images.Any >>>There is nothing called "Any"

Comment: Have you added the Linq using statement??

Comment: just add `using System.Linq;` before all your code - this is a using statement. With it the `Any` method does not exist indeed!

Answer (score 0):

`ImageList` is a special thing and it may or may not be the right object to use..

One good thing about it is that it stores the images not as type `Image`; this is good because it doesn't need a `GDI` handle for each image it stores, even if you add a large number of images.

One problem with this is that you simply can't compare its images to an image you have assigned to a `PictureBox.Image`.

So even after correcting your syntax this will not work:

```
// assign an image
pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[2];
// now look for it:
foreach (var  img in imageList1.Images)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image  == img )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found the Image!");  // won't happen
    }
}
```

Instead you should store the `Key` to the image in the `ImageList`:

```
pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[2];
pictureBox1.Tag = imageList1.Images.Keys[2];
```

Now you can easily look for the key:

```
foreach (var  imgKey in imageList1.Images.Keys)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Tag.ToString() == imgKey )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found the Image-Key!");  // will happen quite quickly!
    }
}
```

Of course the question if using an `ImageList` is a good idea in the first place is quite another matter..

It is really meant to be used with `ListViews`, `TreeViews` and other Controls that can display small iconic images.

It is limited to 256x256 pixels for instance; also: all its images must have the same size!

But if that is OK, stay with it.

Otherwise a `List<Image>`, as Hans suggested would be a natural and flexible alternative..

Comment: Not working... :/ it give an error >> System.NullReferenceError....maybe I have to use ListViews or Treeviews...but how?

Comment: No it doesn't, it works fine here. You need to learn to be more explicit in your communication! Shall I have to guess __which line gives__ this error?? Did you assign the __Tag__? How did you fill the imagelist? Does it have its __Keys__ set? - And no, you don't have to use ListViews or TreeViews if you just want to display small images. do they display at all?

Comment: It gives System.NullReferenceError in "if (pictureBox1.Tag.ToString() == imgKey)" line

Comment: So you have probably not set the Tag as suggested in the code.

Comment: Then, for God's sake use the debugger to fiond out which part is null!!! (Move the cursor over it when in break ode and you'll find out.) The report back!